# How can I use switch statement in codeigniter form_dropdown?

Tags: codeigniter, switch-statement

I want to use switch statement in codeigniter form_dropdown.
My code seems like:

```
$schedule_options = array();
foreach($schedules as $schedule){
$schedule_options[$schedule->scheduleId] = .$schedule->scheduleDays.' - '.$schedule->scheduleTime; 
}
echo form_dropdown('classScheduleId', $schedule_options, set_value('classScheduleId', $class->classScheduleId));
```

I want to switch $schedule_options before having it printed in form_dropdown.

for example:

```
switch($schedule_options) {
   case 'even': 
         echo 'Even Days'; 
         break;
   case'odd': 
         echo 'Odd Days';
         break;
};
```

How can I do that?! Everywhere I put it, I get an Unexpected switch error!

Comment: hmmm it better if you could do you logic on the controller or model before passing onto views. Can you not filter the array before sending it to the views?

Comment: would you please give me an example?!

Comment: it seems no one has got the answer hmm?